# LINQ query problem

Tags: c#, linq

Can't get any result in feeds.
feedXML has the correct data.

```
XDocument feedXML = XDocument.Load(@"http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=twitter");

var feeds = from entry in feedXML.Descendants("entry")
            select new
            {
                PublicationDate = entry.Element("published").Value,
                Title = entry.Element("title").Value
            };
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you getting in feeds?  Are you getting any exceptions?   Would you please post a snippet of the xml?

Comment: Are there any namespaces in the XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a namespace on both the Descendents and Element methods.

```
XDocument feedXML = XDocument.Load(@"http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=twitter");

XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var feeds = from entry in feedXML.Descendants(ns + "entry")
            select new
            {
            PublicationDate = entry.Element(ns + "published").Value,
            Title = entry.Element(ns + "title").Value
            };
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the namespace:

```
// This is the default namespace within the feed, as specified
// xmlns="..." 
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

var feeds = from entry in feedXML.Descendants(ns + "entry")
            ...
```

Namespace handling is beautifully easy in LINQ to XML compared with *everything* other XML API I've ever used :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the XML returned by the HTTP request, you will see that it has an XML namespace defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" ...>
  <id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:search/twitter</id>
  ...
</feed>
```

XML is just like C#, if you use an element name with the wrong namespace, it is not considered to be the same element! You need to add the required namepsace to your query:

```
private static string AtomNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

public static XName Entry = XName.Get("entry", AtomNamespace);

public static XName Published = XName.Get("published", AtomNamespace);

public static XName Title = XName.Get("title", AtomNamespace);

var items = doc.Descendants(AtomConst.Entry)
                .Select(entryElement => new FeedItemViewModel()
                new {
                  Title = entryElement.Descendants(AtomConst.Title).Single().Value,
                  ...
                });
```

Comment: Any reason for not making these readonly, and not making AtomNamespace of type XNamespace? (I also rather like the + operator to reduce fluff.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `feedXML.Descendants("entry")`.  This is returning 0 results
According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) you need to put in a fully qualified XName